# Crashlytics Flutter iOS: not logging RAM and disk free data

Tags: ios, firebase, crashlytics

There is a default `RAM free` and `Disk free` fields in Device data that are automatically populated when a crash occurs.

In Android this works fine, but in iOS it seems to be logging `0 B` for those two fields.

[image]

Is that a bug, an iOS limitation in Crashlytics or did I forget to set up something?

Comment: I can't confirm this but my theory is that RAM free: 0 B and Disk free: 0 B means it happened in the background. I have an event that it's showing 98% of them happened in the background and most of those individual logs (possibly 98%) are showing 0 for RAM and Disk free. My other crashes don't show 0.

Comment: This problem happens for every iOS crashlytics logs, even in non-fatal errors that happen with the app in foreground

Answer (score 0):

I see the same thing. While I haven't confirmed this from any source, my hunch is that the ram / disk metric comes from crash reports because that info is included in it at the time of crash.